# Using Pattern in regex verbose

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Trying to get output using re.VERBOSE

I'm trying to change pattern code is as shown

I tried some code but it's not showing anything because it return none

original

```
    taf_header_pattern = """
        ^
        (TAF)?    # TAF header (at times missing or duplicate)
        \s*
        (?P<type> (COR|AMD|AMD\sCOR|COR\sAMD|RTD)){0,1}
        \s* # There may or may not be space as COR/AMD/RTD is optional
        (?P<icao_code> [A-Z]{4}) # Station ICAO code
        \s* # at some aerodromes does not appear
        (?P<origin_date> \d{0,2}) # at some aerodromes does not appear
        (?P<origin_hours> \d{0,2}) # at some aerodromes does not appear
        (?P<origin_minutes> \d{0,2}) # at some aerodromes does not appear
        Z? # Zulu time (UTC, that is) # at some aerodromes does not appear
        \s*
        (?P<valid_from_date> \d{0,2})
        (?P<valid_from_hours> \d{0,2})
        /
        (?P<valid_till_date> \d{0,2})
        (?P<valid_till_hours> \d{0,2})
    """
```

Changed

```
    taf_header_pattern = """
        ^
        (?P<icao_code> [A-Z]{4}) # Station ICAO code
        \s*
        (?P<fix_code> (FIXED BASE)) # FIXED BASE
        \s*
        (?P<type> (COR|AMD|AMD\sCOR|COR\sAMD|RTD)){0,1}
        \s* # There may or may not be space as COR/AMD/RTD is optional
        (?P<origin_date> \d{0,2}) # at some aerodromes does not appear
        (?P<origin_hours> \d{0,2}) # at some aerodromes does not appear
        (?P<origin_minutes> \d{0,2}) # at some aerodromes does not appear
        Z? # Zulu time (UTC, that is) # at some aerodromes does not appear
        \s*
        (?P<valid_from_date> \d{0,2})
        (?P<valid_from_hours> \d{0,2})
        /
        (?P<valid_till_date> \d{0,2})
        (?P<valid_till_hours> \d{0,2})
    """

test_string00 = "KIND FIXED BASE 3117Z-0117Z"
test_string01 = "KGEG FIXED BASE AMD02 3119Z-0110Z 311958Z"
test_string02 = "KGEG FIXED BASE AMD02 COR01 3119Z-0110Z 311958Z"

header_taf = re.match(taf_header_pattern, string, re.VERBOSE)

print(header_taf)
```

It returns none which it should not be doing

Comment: A  couple of things: in the verbose mode, you either need to escape whitespaces if they're wanted or get rid of them. Additionally there's no forward slash in either of your strings but you require one. See https://regex101.com/r/lDa96G/2

Comment: It is certain you must change `FIXED BASE` to `FIXED\ BASE`, but the rest is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
^
(?P<icao_code> [A-Z]{4}) # Station ICAO code
\s*
(?P<fix_code> (FIXED\ BASE)) # FIXED BASE
\s*
(?P<type>(AMD\d{2}\sCOR\d{2}|COR\d{2}|AMD\d{2})){0,1}
\s* # There may or may not be space as COR/AMD/RTD is optional
(?P<valid_from_date>\d{0,2})
(?P<valid_from_hours>\d{0,2}) 
Z?
\-?
(?P<valid_till_date>\d{0,2})
(?P<valid_till_hours>\d{0,2})  
Z?
\s* # There may or may not be space as COR/AMD/RTD is optional
(?P<origin_date>\d{0,2}) # at some aerodromes does not appear
(?P<origin_hours>\d{0,2}) # at some aerodromes does not appear
(?P<origin_minutes>\d{0,2}) # at some aerodromes does not appear
Z?
```

This works